# Passing a path with '/' to $resource or $http factory

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to pass a parameter containing `/` to Factory? Want to accomplish something like

```
.factory('MyData', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('http://1.2.3.4/:urlFragment', {
   urlFragment : '' // default empty
     }, {
            getData : {
                method : 'GET'
            },
```

And calling it

```
$scope.scopeVar = MyData.getData({urlFragment : '/some/path/to/data'});
```

Looking at the network console, I see that `/` are replaced with `%2`.

Can I encode the passed parameter inside Factory? (Using `$http` or `$resource`).

Or in general, how can I execute any functions on parameters inside factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't really get access to the url inside of your factory because `$resource` automatically handles it.  But thankfully Angular gives you a way to get access to the url before it is called by using the `$resource` directly.  Looking at the docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource), one of the actions you can supply in your `$resource` declaration is a `transformRequest` property.

```
return $resource('http://1.2.3.4/:urlFragment', {urlFragment: ''}, {
    getData: {method: 'GET', transformRequest: function(data, headers){
        // make your modifications here to either data or headers
    }}
});
```

Although I haven't actually run this code, I believe that should allow you to do what you want.  Let me know if it doesn't.